# Which port the android emulator is connected to network

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

In my host machine I launched android emulator and my host machine is connected two network one is wifi network and another one is LTE network my question is for which network my emulator is connected. which port is connected to emulator. how to find com number(windows it is com number).

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: i think its 5555 but no sure

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html